# Beginning with infinitives to provide further explanation?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context, infinitive-clauses

I know I can start a sentence with an infinitive. However, in this case I am not sure whether I can start with it to provide further explanation. Is it correct?

Therefore, I want to use this master to deepen my educational background. **To study** the approaches and policies implemented in Canada to find whether I could adapt them back in my country to improve our situation.

Comment: That does not read smoothly.I would link the two sentences with and instead but there must be many ways to reword this.

Comment: It isn't really necessary to separate the two words with a full-stop (or period). It sounds unnatural in this context. Therefore, the beginning of the sentence with an infinitive sounds odd too.

Comment: This way?: *Therefore, I want to use this master to deepen my educational background and to study the approaches implemented in Canada to find if their adaptation could improve the situation in my country.*

Comment: Your example text *To study the approaches and policies implemented in Canada to find whether I could adapt them back in my country to improve our situation* is not a sentence, any more than ***To die*** is a sentence. You need at the very least an "active" verb, and usually something else besides: *To die **sucks**. To die **is to stop living**.*